# Why my telegram bot (aiogram) doesn't work right?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

**the bot offers to guess a number from 0 to 10. But for the correct answer, it answers "False"**

I guess the problem is using asynchronous functions, but I'm not good at them

````
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import random

bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# number to guess
NUMBER = 0


# comes up with a number
def setRand():
    NUMBER = random.randrange(10)
    print(NUMBER)


# handler for /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(msg: types.Message):
    setRand()
    await msg.answer("Try to guess the number from 0 to 10")


# handler for getting answer
@dp.message_handler()
async def getNumber(msg: types.Message):
    if msg.text == str(NUMBER):
        await msg.answer('True!')
    else:
        await msg.answer('False :с')
        await msg.answer('But I came up with new number!')

        setRand()


executor.start_polling(dp)```
````

Comment: "But for the correct answer, it answers "False"" - how do you know your answer was correct? Because the bot changes the secret number on every wrong guess.

Comment: I always know correct answer. I see it in PyCharm console :). In function setRand I use print() for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use global for global variables!

````
def setRand():
    global NUMBER
    NUMBER = random.randrange(10)
    print(NUMBER)```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).